# Where can I get some practical experience with analyzing data using classical linear regression?

Tags: regression, dataset

I have an interview coming up where one of the rounds is a dataset round. It'll be some sort of linear regression analysis. I feel that I have a solid understanding of linear regression with OLS and variants like ridge, lasso, weighted least squares, etc...But I don't have much practical experience.

What's a good resource where I can get some practice with analyizing data using linear regression *efficiently* (I don't have months or weeks to spend on this. Maybe 40 hours max spread out over a month).

I was thinking Kaggle tutorials for linear regression. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought of reproducing or extending analyses presented here on CV and checking them against the posted solutions?  There are (literally) thousands of such examples, many given in great detail and conducted by several people in several ways.  In a small fraction of your 40 hours you can gain that practical experience.

Comment: @whuber I haven't thought about that. That's a good point. I will try that. I haven't read too many posts with practical analyses on here. Is there a particular tag that I can search for that'll show these kind of posts, or should I search for "regression" and look through those?

Comment: Good question.  Searching here usually requires multiple attempts (because the search syntax is limited and matching is relatively inflexible).  A good start is https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=regression%20real%20data.  This capitalizes on the local search ability to use votes and other indicators of status (whether Q or A, for instance).  For more focused searches, use Google's engine, as in https://www.google.com/search?q=regression+data+example+real+site%3Astats.stackexchange.com